# Confuse about function prototype and object.getPrototypeOf

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

I know there are three approach to get an object's prototype, in the follow example the three approach result are the same:

```
    function Person(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    Person.prototype.say = function () {
        console.log("hello");
    }

    var person = new Person();

    console.log(person.constructor.prototype); //Person {say: function}
    console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(person)); //Person {say: function}
    console.log(person.__proto__); //Person {say: function}
```

but when check an object which create by `Object.create`, the result seems different:

```
    var person = {
        name: "Lee",
        age: "12"
    }

    var per1 = Object.create(person);

    console.log(per1.constructor.prototype) //Object {}
    console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(per1)) //Object {name: "Lee", age: "12"}
    console.log(per1.__proto__) //Object {name: "Lee", age: "12"}
```

Doesn't the object will follow its constructor function's prototype? How to explain the above example?

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/A9SsM/

Answer (score 0):

`getPrototypeof` was just an implementation of `__proto__` but they are both considered deprecated or non-standard now.  As for your third example, I do not believe you got any output because it should be `per1.prototype.constructor`.  If you didn't mean that, I can not find that function documented anywhere within constructor.